# Who am I? - Riddles

Tags: riddle

> I am small, tall, and I maul.
>
> I killed your family, but innocent I am.
>
> I killed your friend, yet look at who I am.
>
> I haunt the shadows, I saw you yesterday,
>
> Killed your friend the next day.

Who am I?

Comment: (You should really give your puzzles more distinctive names. Some people even use the name of the puzzle as an additional hint to the puzzle, but at a minimum, something less generic than Who/What Am I would make for a less bland presentation.)

Comment: Got any hints? It would help.

Comment: @Colea you say "riddles" - are these all leading to the same answer, or are they separate riddles?

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have enough reputation to leave this as a comment instead of an answer - is this

> a lawnmower?

or

> a shaver?

I am small, tall, and I maul.

> Mauling suggests destroying something, in this case mowing grass and shaving hair would both qualify. Tall applies to both, as they are longer than wide - however small would probably relate more to a shaver.

I killed your family, but innocent I am.

> A lawnmower and shaver can "kill" a family of grass or hair, but since they are not humans or animals, this doesn't make the object "guilty" of murder.

I killed your friend, yet look at who I am.

> I have no idea what this means.

I haunt the shadows, I saw you yesterday,

> In the case of a lawnmower, it would be stored in a dark garage/store room, hence haunting the shadows - in the case of a shaver, haunting five o' clock shadows, I suppose (since shaving kills five o' clock shadows off)? It's more likely to be a shaver as someone is more likely to shave everyday than mow the lawn daily.

Killed your friend the next day.

> Self explanatory

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site as well as Can you give proper explanation as of how it is the answer you gave. Please explain each line in its reference.

Comment: Hi Maniraj, thanks for the welcome. I've expanded on my answer

Comment: I think your explanations might be even more fitting for a slightly different kind of tool. Namely - lumberjacks axe( with a wooden handle to fit in with line #3)?

Comment: Hi Oleksii, that's interesting - I still don't get "yet look at who I am", is that where the wooden handle fits in with line 3? Do you mind letting me know what you mean? :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Silence?

I am small, tall, and I maul.

> It is a small thing and the silent treatment can hurt.

I killed your family, but innocent I am.
I killed your friend, yet look at who I am.

> It is not the silence's fault but yours for putting up that barrier.

I haunt the shadows, I saw you yesterday,
Killed your friend the next day.

> The shadows and silent.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Blender?

I am small, tall, and I maul.

> Blenders are small, they are taller than they are wide, and they chop up all the fruit that they can.

I killed your family, but innocent I am.

> I am some sort of fruit in this case, and you blended the same fruit a different day. But since we are all inanimate objects, it can't be considered murder. Also a blender is a tool, and it is the person who is "killing" the fruit.

I killed your friend, yet look at who I am.

> Same reasoning as above. The friend is a member of a different fruit or vegetable family

I haunt the shadows, I saw you yesterday,

> Blenders are typically stored in cabinets when not in use. Because the owner uses the blender daily, the blender sees all the fruit that is displayed on the counter.

Killed your friend the next day.

> It blended another fruit or vegetable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Stranger?

I am small, tall, and I maul.

> Perhaps this is a reference to stranger danger

I killed your friend, yet look at who I am.

> When you know someone, they are no longer a stranger but become a friend

I haunt the shadows, I saw you yesterday,

> Strangers are everywhere and see you every day

Killed your friend the next day.

> Strangers can also kill or end friendships